# Removing items by its contained text from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

I'm looking for a solution to remove items from my html when the page is loaded.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Модули <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><strong>blabla</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/admin/logentry/">blabla6</a>                
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><strong>blabla5</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/apartment/">blabla4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/entrance/">blabla3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/entrancekasasummary/">blabla2</a>
        </li>         
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/paymentscashier/">blabl1</a>                
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So I want to remove for example blabla4, blabla2, blabla1 including their `<li>` tags

This is what I've tried so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // select relevant elements 
    var elements = $('content-main'); 
    // go through the elements and find the one with the value
    elements.each(function(index, domElement) { 
        var $element = $(domElement);
        // does the element have the text we're looking for?
        if ($element.text() === "blabla2") {
            $element.hide(); // hide the element with jQuery return false;
            // jump out of the each 
        } 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, otherwise no one will help you.

Comment: This is what I've tried so far `<script type="text/javascript">
// select relevant elements
var elements = $('content-main');

// go through the elements and find the one with the value
elements.each(function(index, domElement) {
    var $element = $(domElement);

    // does the element have the text we're looking for?
    if ($element.text() === "blabla2") {
        $element.hide();
            // hide the element with jQuery
        return false;
            // jump out of the each
    }
});
</script>`

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, why haven't you picked an answer yet? If not, why haven't you commented accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Just collect the list items, cast the resulting `NodeList` to an `Array`, and iterate over it, removing items whose `innerHTML` contains 'blabla'.

```js
const listitems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu li'));

for (const listitem of listitems) {
  if (listitem.innerHTML.indexOf('blabla') != -1) {
    listitem.parentNode.removeChild(listitem);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><strong>blabla</strong></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/admin/logentry/">blabla6</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><strong>blabla5</strong></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/entrances/apartment/">blabla4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/entrances/entrance/">blabla3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/entrances/entrancekasasummary/">blabla2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/entrances/paymentscashier/">blabl1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the selector [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and the function [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select the parent element `li`.

This approach removes the element `li` with text `blabla4`

```js
$('#remove').on('click', function() {
  $("li a:contains(blabla4)").closest('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Модули <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>blabla</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/admin/logentry/">blabla6</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>blabla5</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/entrances/apartment/">blabla4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/entrances/entrance/">blabla3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/entrances/entrancekasasummary/">blabla2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/entrances/paymentscashier/">blabl1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id='remove'>remove blabla4</button>
```

Comment: Why not simply `$(".dropdown-menu li:contains(blabla4)").remove();`. Btw, I wouldn't even consider using jQuery for the task.

Comment: @connexo why not jQuery?  the question is tagged with that library.

Comment: Because it's slow, fat and totally unnecessary for this.

Comment: @connexo but for some reason, the OP has tagged with jQuery.

Comment: They also tagged [tag:javascript].

Comment: @connexo yes, and so?

Comment: I'm not downvoting or anything, just saying that imo throwing jQuery at this is useless overhead. It simply has no benefit, but it has serious downsides as mentioned. It's like using a car to drive five meters instead of walking.

Comment: @connexo for me is ok! this is an alternative according to the OP's requirements and the current libraries he's using.  Like I said, the OP has tagged with jQuery, so this is a valid alternative.

Comment: Ok, then keep driving the shortest of distances instead of walking (which would be faster and less waste of resources in those cases). I'd suggest you learn walking instead, and teach others what you've learnt then. You might end up finding out you don't need jQuery at all. :D

Comment: I mean, there definitely **is** usecases for jQuery. This, though, is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery .remove() to delete HTML tags, But you should have a selector on the tags that you want to remove:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').find("li").slice(4, 5).remove();
    $('.dropdown-menu').find("li").slice(5, 6).remove();
    $('.dropdown-menu').find("li").slice(5, 6).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Модули <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><strong>blabla</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/admin/logentry/">blabla6</a>                
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><strong>blabla5</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/apartment/">blabla4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/entrance/">blabla3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/entrancekasasummary/">blabla2</a>
        </li>         
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/paymentscashier/">blabl1</a>                
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a array data structure that will hold the values for which `<li>` should be removed then loop over to all the `<li>` tags inside the class `dropdown-menu` and remove them based on their content match with the array value:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var removeText = ['blabla4', 'blabla2', 'blabla1'];
  $('.dropdown-menu li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('a').text().trim();
    if(removeText.indexOf(text) !== -1){
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Модули <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><strong>blabla</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/admin/logentry/">blabla6</a>                
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><strong>blabla5</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/apartment/">blabla4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/entrance/">blabla3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/entrancekasasummary/">blabla2</a>
        </li>         
        <li>
                <a href="/entrances/paymentscashier/">blabl1</a>                
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JQuery:

```
$(".dropdown-menu > li > a").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.html() == 'bla bla bla') {
        $this.parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This code has more problems than I feel willing to address.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the items using `querySelectorAll`, convert the NodeList to Array with `Array.from`, then iterate over each item and remove it.

```js
const wordsToRemove = ['blabla3', 'blabla2'];
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li > a'));

const result = items
  .filter(item => wordsToRemove.includes(item.textContent))
  .forEach(item => item.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(item.parentNode));
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Модули <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>blabla</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/admin/logentry/">blabla6</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>blabla5</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/entrances/apartment/">blabla4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/entrances/entrance/">blabla3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/entrances/entrancekasasummary/">blabla2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/entrances/paymentscashier/">blabl1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Which is exactly what my answer from 6 minutes earlier suggests.